# Joining a CSV file to a grid in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, csv

In ArcGIS Pro I have two files that I am currently working with. On the one hand, a polygon grid from which I have selected 10,000 cells. Each of these cells has its own ID. On the other hand, I have a CSV file. There, each cell with the same ID as that of the grid is assigned different information. I would like to connect the data with the grid cells.

[image: Gridcells]

My first thought was to open the CSV file in Excel and then import it with "excel to table". Unfortunately, the CSV is much too large for Excel because of the many rows, so my selection is not output. I imported the CSV directly into my project, but I can't join the information from the csv to the grid with "join Field". I also tried to import the CSV into my geodatabase, but got an error message there.

Is there a possibility that I have not considered or do I have to get to grips with Python in this respect? Unfortunately, my knowledge of Python is not very good.

To show a screenshot of the error message, I tried again to join the grid with the CSV using "join Field". However, I don't get any message at the moment, but the progress remains at 0% sind 30 minutes.

Comment: What do you mean by joining data to a raster? Thats not a standard process. You need to explain your data fully. For example you can't join data to a float raster as the only type of join you could do is on an integer raster and you seem to be indicating you want to join data to ever cell. To have an integer raster where every cell is a unique value is unusual indeed. Edit your question and add more explanation.

Comment: You are right. I tried to make it more clear and changed my question. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Please add more detail, a screen shot of the properties of your raster, it's not clear if it is a float raster, also include an example of what is in your CSV file, so people can understand the structure of the data. As it stands its too vague to understand why the join should be failing?

Comment: You have several different problems presented here, with insufficient details on any of them to identify the problem (besides allowing Excel within a light-year of GIS data). Join is a fairly basic task, but it requires strong typing and pedantic formatting. Loading CSV into a file geodatabase table is also a basic task, with multiple potential methodologies. Please [Edit] the Question to focus on one task, and the details (including data samples) necessary to address that task

Comment: @Vince your comment about _allowing Excel within a light-year of GIS data_ really made me chuckle, a ray of sunshine in an otherwise dull Friday!

Comment: I'm sorry. I know, join Field and adding csv to a geodatabase are the absolut basics, but last night and today nothing worked properly. I don't know what I really changed, but now everything worked fine. Really, thanks a lot for the comments!